# Menu.xml programmatically

Tags: android, menu

i have menu.xml like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="@string/settings_shortcut"
        android:icon="@drawable/setting"
        android:title="@string/settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:alphabeticShortcut="@string/info_shortcut"
        android:icon="@drawable/info"
        android:title="@string/info"/>
</menu>
```

Now we usually do it like this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    return true;
    }
```

But how can i do this programatically ? without using xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [Menu.add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#add%28int,%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

For example, to create a "New" menu with an id

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, id, 0, "New"); 

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: hey i tried this too menu.add(R.string.settings_label).setIcon(R.drawable.setting); but how can i refer in onOptionsItemSelected ?

Comment: use my example... there the id is set.. you can check the id in onOptionItemSelected

Comment: one more thing buddy how can i add shortcut?